# Node.js: 100M elements in 1D vs 2D Array — Unexpected Memory Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, memory-management, v8

Let's say I have 100 million random `floats` I'm trying to save in an array.

At first, I was saving the numbers in a 2D array (basically a matrix), but then I thought maybe I could make the whole thing faster if I stored all 100M elements in a single linear 1D array.

To my surprise, this happened:

### 10 000 × 10 000 2D Array

Creation and manipulation of the array is quite fast, Node runs without any troubles *even on default memory limit*.

### 100M—element 1D Array

When trying to generate 100M random floats Node throws
`FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`
even when called with `--max_old_space_size=8192`

### Why is that?

It seems very counter-intuitive to me. My guess was making a single long Array object should be much more memory-efficient than storing 10k Arrays in another Array.

So, yeah, my question is: **why is that?**

Comment: I just typed in a one-line Node program to create a 100,000,000 element Array instance and it worked fine. What does your code look like?

Comment: It should work fine. What value do you try to assign to the `array.length` property?

Comment: @Pointy var MAT = [], m = 0;
 while (m < rows) {
  MAT[m] = Math.random()*100;
  m++;
 }

Comment: I also forgot to point out it actually works with integers, both random and same valued ( = sparse array)

Comment: @Pointy Did you use something like new Array(100000000).fill(0) or what? :)

Comment: Sorry no; I just allocated. When I use your code I get the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changes in implementation from version to version, but in general there are hard limits placed on the size of an individual object. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3505 for details on that.

In the first case, you essentially have an array of 10000 pointers to other arrays, each only of size 10000 themselves. They don't need to be contiguous in memory - unlike the second example where you have an actual block of 100000000 in a single object. So you hit a (totally arbitrary) cap set by the Node runtime (as the link above and comment below point out, this is a facet of V8, not Node specifically).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So Node sets its own limit, breaking native JS's 2^31-1 Array size limit?

Comment: The limit is in V8, not Node. It's currently 512MB for an array containing double values. Due to the growth strategy, you actually get to use a little less than the theoretical limit, namely around 50M elements (of 8 bytes each).

Comment: @jmrk Thanks for the clarification. Is there any official documentation for such things?

Comment: @rkysely: Not that I'm aware of; only the source: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/objects.h (look for "class FixedDoubleArray" and then "kMaxSize" in there). 
Documenting limits accurately is difficult, because in many cases the specifics depend on usage details (specific example: if you use "new Array(100000000);", then you'll actually run into a different limit).

Comment: @jmrk Oh, I see now—this is also helpful, thank you :)